# How to Change jdbc schema users with mytable in OAuth2 spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-jdbc

I have to change the name of default schema users with mytable name.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
        
        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
        
        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;
        
        @Bean
        TokenStore jdbcTokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(jdbcTokenStore());
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.jdbc(dataSource);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
            security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }
        
    }
```

this is my securityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery("select USER_LOGIN_ID,USER_PASSWORD "
                + "from MY_TABLE "
                + "where USER_LOGIN_ID = ?");

        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(""); // Remove the ROLE_ prefix
    }
}
```

this is my resouceserver

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/secure").authenticated();
    }

}
```

and i have create customer table here

which ius here

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable {

    @Column(name = "USER_LOGIN_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userLoginId;
    @Column(name = "USER_PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String userPassword;
}
```

here url which i use.

http://localhost:8081/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=user

and it is throwing error

{
"timestamp": 1621689938591,
"status": 401,
"error": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Unauthorized",
"path": "/oauth/token"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use your own table you have to authenticationmanager to read user from that table like below. It should be able to provide user and authority details.
You can create your own configuration class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and override configure method like below.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                   .dataSource(dataSource)
                   .usersByUsernameQuery("select userid,password,enabled "
                     + "from yourtable"
                     + "where userid = ?")
                   .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select userid,authority "
                    + "from yourauthoritytable"
                    + "where userid= ?");
    }
```

Comment: hi batflix, Thank you for this solution but when i add this method i am getting internal server error,

Comment: It should be added to the class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.

Comment: yes, i added this method in exteded WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @berzerk answer, you can use a more modern approach instead of using the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

You can provide your own `UserDetailsService` bean with your custom queries.

```java
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    jdbcUserDetailsManager.setUsersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled "
                + "from mytable "
                + "where username = ?");

    return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
}
```

Note that if you have changed the `authorities` table or any other table that `JdbcUserDetailsManager` uses by default, you should change the queries the same way that was done with `setUsersByUsernameQuery`

You can also refer to the [Spring Security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/jdbc.html) for more details about the `UserDetailsService` custom implementations.